# How to immediately give user a random username after signing in for the first time with Next-Auth?

Tags: mongodb, next.js, next-auth

I am trying to assign random username after user is registered.

Example "username133241341234".

I think I have to do something like this in my [...nextauth].js file, but could not solve the issue.


Using @next-auth/mongodb-adapter by the way.

```
callbacks: {
        async session({ session, token }) {
            if (session?.user) {
                session.user.id = token.uid;
                session.user.username = `${session.user.name.split` `[0]}${Date.now()}`;
            }
            return session;
        },
}
```